# changing a specific 'column' inside a txt file

Tags: search, replace, cut

I have a file with thousands of entries like this:

```
6/05/2016,32,34,40,45,48,,01,10
10/05/2016,02,26,27,40,49,,05,10
13/05/2016,07,15,28,31,42,,10,11
17/05/2016,15,27,32,36,39,,03,10
```

I want to replace the date on the first field with a sequential number, starting with 800. So this list would be transformed in

```
800,32,34,40,45,48,,01,10
801,02,26,27,40,49,,05,10
802,07,15,28,31,42,,10,11
803,15,27,32,36,39,,03,10
...
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` it's as simple as

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1=n++; print}' n=800 file
```

You set the input and output delimiters to `,` via `-F,` and `-vOFS=,` and initialize a variable `n` to `800` using `n=800`. The "action" statement `{$1=n++; print}` executes for each record, setting the first field to a post-incrementing `n` and printing the reconstituted record

Comment: amazing. Can you explain what each part is doing? thanks.

Comment: @SpaceDog, added some more explanation